# How  can I call asp page with parameters from html link?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I´m trying to call asp page from html link but with paremeters. Is that possible?

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="<% Response.redirect("myurl with parameters")%>">Caducados</a></li>
```

I know why this fails but is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass them in a conventional link;

```
 <a href="page.asp?a=b&c=<%=serverval %>&d=e">Caducados</a>
```

If you need client side processing

```
 <a href="#" onclick="goTo('val1', '<%=serverval %>');">Caducados</a>
```

and a js helper;

```
 function goTo(a,b) {
   location.href = "page.asp?a=" + a + "&b= ....
```

Comment: the parameter I want to pass has been posted by another asp page. I think it is in the current url. How can I reference it in js?

Comment: thanks a lot. I have passed the paremeter from asp to js and then use your solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
<li><a href="mypage.asp?param1=value1&param2=value2">Caducados</a></li>
```

Comment: at the first thanks. The parameter I want to pass is in asp variable

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. Thanks Alex K and My other Me

```
<% 
  id_usuario= Request.QueryString("usuario")
%>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function goTo () {
    var a = <%=id_usuario%>
    alert(a)        
    }
</script>
```

and then call goTo function from onclick event in html link