# HTML page displays vbscript code, instead of running the script. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, vbscript, asp-classic

So, I created a small asp page where I pull up some data from AD and display it into a table. If I try to open "abc.asp" page, it displays properly, displaying the table. Simple stuff.

Now, I tried to move the code to an html file, so that it is easy to link the html document in different parts of website. So, I can open "abc.html" which is basically just an empty html document, with the asp code wrapped in script tags as below.

```
<script language="vbscript" runat="server">Response.Write "<h1>Testing</h1>"...</script>
```

Now, I have no idea what the hell is wrong. But, the code is displayed as is, instead of actually running the code and displaying the result. I am pretty sure I am missing something small, but I can't figure it out. So, here I am, trying to figure out the reason.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I dun goofed selecting all the suggested tags without thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your webserver is not set up to serve HTML files with asp code. Change the extension to .asp and not .html. Both of them are not same and differ in their Server control support.

Comment: How do I configure the web server then? I have enabled ASP scripts in IIS already. Do I need to add something else?

Comment: No problem you use Iframe inside the html code call whenever needed. <html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
<iframe id="frame1" width="600px" height="300px" frameborder="0" scroll="no" src="abc.asp"></iframe>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2):

You should save the file as **abc.asp** not **abc.html** ;-)

How do you think the server identify the asp code? From the extension of the file

Comment: Actually, abc.asp worked fine. I wanted to create an html document which can access asp script, just like it access js files. But, somehow, it is going crazy. I tried using js to write simple text, but somehow the system is not even bothered with script tag.

Comment: Exactly, the server reconised it needed to some work with the `.asp` page. That is the purpose of the `.asp` extention. WIth the `.html` page the server does not know it needs to do anything other than serve the page. YOu could set up IIS to interperate `.html` pages as `.asp` but I would advise against it. `.html` pages are generally static, `.asp` dynamic

Comment: Ok. So, in that case, should I use an iframe element to call the asp page inside of html page? Will that cause any problem?

Comment: No Problem, but why not just link to the `.asp` pages and serve those instead? Or convert your `.html` pages to `.asp`?

Comment: You can call your .asp page within html without any issue. Have a look at the examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793891/how-can-i-call-asp-page-with-parameters-from-html-link

Comment: @JonP Because the devs I am working with are stupid. They can't do anything more than call an html page from the applications they have created. Anything more and they will act dumb as hell. Think about it, they were wondering why I need access to AD listing to just see the user list. Anyway, I will just create an empty html page and use full width iframe to reference asp page.

Comment: You don't need an iFrame. Just call the .asp page within your html page using JavaScript or VbScript. See the link I posted in these comments